# GnuRadio installation problem: Python module click is required for gr-modtool

Tags: linux-mint, gnuradio, uhd

I have a Mint Box mini pc with OS v.19 cinamon. I'm trying to install gnuradio + uhd.
I did the following:

```
udo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Note: 
I encountered a gconf2 error while installing some packages. So, the solution is:
sudo dpkg --configure -a

then:

sudo apt-get upgrade



Install Dependencies
Bionic Beaver (18.04)


sudo apt install git cmake g++ libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev swig python3-numpy \
python3-mako python3-sphinx python3-lxml doxygen libfftw3-dev libcomedi-dev \
libsdl1.2-dev libgsl-dev libqwt-qt5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev python3-pyqt5 \
liblog4cpp5-dev libzmq3-dev python3-yaml 

git clone --recursive https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio.git

or

git clone --recursive git@github.com:gnuradio/gnuradio.git

Configure and build GNU Radio:

cd gnuradio
mkdir build
cd build
```

and when I tried the:

```
cmake ../

I got this issue:

fit-pc@fitpc-fitlet2:~/gnuradio/build$ cmake ../
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Build type set to Release.
-- Extracting version information from git describe...
-- Compiler Version: cc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
-- Compiler Flags: /usr/bin/cc:::-O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized
/usr/bin/c++:::-O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized
-- ADDING PERF COUNTERS
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   program_options
--   filesystem
--   system
--   regex
--   thread
--   unit_test_framework
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- User set python executable /usr/bin/python3
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found suitable exact version "3.6.8") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found suitable version "3.6.8", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Python checking for six - python 2 and 3 compatibility library - found
-- 
-- Checking for module SWIG
-- Found SWIG version 3.0.12.
-- 
-- The build system will automatically enable all components.
-- Use -DENABLE_DEFAULT=OFF to disable components by default.
-- 
-- Configuring python-support support...
--   Dependency PYTHONLIBS_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency SWIG_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency SWIG_VERSION_CHECK = TRUE
--   Dependency SIX_FOUND = TRUE
--   Enabling python-support support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_PYTHON=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring testing-support support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Enabling testing-support support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_TESTING=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring VOLK support...
-- Build type set to Release.
-- Extracting version information from git describe...
-- 
-- Python checking for python >= 2.7
-- Python checking for python >= 2.7 - found
-- 
-- Python checking for mako >= 0.4.2
-- Python checking for mako >= 0.4.2 - found
-- 
-- Python checking for six - python 2 and 3 compatibility library
-- Python checking for six - python 2 and 3 compatibility library - found
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Checking for module 'orc-0.4 > 0.4.11'
--   No package 'orc-0.4' found
-- orc files (missing: ORC_LIBRARY ORC_INCLUDE_DIR ORCC_EXECUTABLE) 
-- QA Testing is enabled.
--   Modify using: -DENABLE_TESTING=ON/OFF
-- System profiling is disabled.
--   Modify using: -DENABLE_PROFILING=ON/OFF
-- Compiler name: GNU
-- x86* CPU detected
-- Compiler doesn't support NEON, Overruled arch neon
-- Compiler doesn't support NEON, Overruled arch neonv7
-- Compiler doesn't support NEON, Overruled arch neonv8
-- ORC support not found, Overruled arch orc
-- CPU width is 64 bits, Overruled arch 32
-- Available architectures: generic;64;3dnow;abm;popcount;mmx;fma;sse;sse2;norc;sse3;ssse3;sse4_a;sse4_1;sse4_2;avx;avx2;avx512f;avx512cd
-- Available machines: generic;sse2_64_mmx;sse3_64_mmx;ssse3_64_mmx;sse4_a_64_mmx;sse4_1_64_mmx;sse4_2_64_mmx;avx_64_mmx;avx2_64_mmx;avx512f_64_mmx;avx512cd_64_mmx
-- BUILD TYPE = RELEASE
-- Base cflags = -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall
-- BUILD INFO ::: generic ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall 
-- BUILD INFO ::: sse2_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2
-- BUILD INFO ::: sse3_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3
-- BUILD INFO ::: ssse3_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3
-- BUILD INFO ::: sse4_a_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -msse4a -mpopcnt
-- BUILD INFO ::: sse4_1_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1
-- BUILD INFO ::: sse4_2_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt
-- BUILD INFO ::: avx_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mavx
-- BUILD INFO ::: avx2_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mavx -mfma -mavx2
-- BUILD INFO ::: avx512f_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mavx -mfma -mavx2 -mavx512f
-- BUILD INFO ::: avx512cd_64_mmx ::: GNU ::: -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -m64 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mavx -mfma -mavx2 -mavx512f -mavx512cd
-- Compiler Version: cc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
-- c flags:  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall;
-- asm flags:  
-- c flags:  -fvisibility=hidden -Wsign-compare -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -Wall;
-- asm flags:   
-- Did not find liborc and orcc, disabling orc support...
-- Loading version 1.4.1git into constants...
-- Using install prefix: /usr/local
-- 
-- Configuring volk support...
--   Enabling volk support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_VOLK=ON/OFF
--   Override with -DENABLE_INTERNAL_VOLK=ON/OFF
-- Checking for module 'gmp'
--   No package 'gmp' found
-- Checking for module 'mpir >= 3.0'
--   No package 'mpir' found
-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- 
-- Configuring doxygen support...
--   Dependency DOXYGEN_FOUND = YES
--   Enabling doxygen support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_DOXYGEN=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring sphinx support...
--   Dependency SPHINX_FOUND = TRUE
--   Enabling sphinx support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_SPHINX=ON/OFF
-- Checking for module 'gmp'
--   No package 'gmp' found
-- Checking for module 'mpir >= 3.0'
--   No package 'mpir' found
-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- 
-- Configuring gnuradio-runtime support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency PYTHONINTERP_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency MPLIB_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency LOG4CPP_FOUND = TRUE
--   Enabling gnuradio-runtime support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-ctrlport support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency SWIG_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency SWIG_VERSION_CHECK = TRUE
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Enabling gr-ctrlport support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_CTRLPORT=ON/OFF
-- Loading build date Fri, 28 Jun 2019 17:37:16 into constants...
-- Loading version 3.8tech-preview-419-gb0e16be2 into constants...
-- Checking for module 'thrift'
--   No package 'thrift' found
-- Binary 'thrift' not found.
-- TRY_SHM_VMCIRCBUF set to ON.
-- 
-- Python checking for python2 >= 2.7.6 or python3 >= 3.4.0 - found
-- Python checking for PyYAML >= 3.10 - found
-- Python checking for mako >= 0.9.1 - found
-- Python checking for pygobject >= 2.28.6 - found
-- Python checking for Gtk (GI) >= 3.10.8 - found
-- Python checking for Cairo (GI) >= 1.0 - found
-- Python checking for PangoCairo (GI) >= 1.0 - found
-- Python checking for numpy - found
-- 
-- Configuring gnuradio-companion support...
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_PYTHON = ON
--   Dependency PYTHON_MIN_VER_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency PYYAML_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency MAKO_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency PYGI_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency GTK_GI_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency CAIRO_GI_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency PANGOCAIRO_GI_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency NUMPY_FOUND = TRUE
--   Enabling gnuradio-companion support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GRC=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-blocks support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Enabling gr-blocks support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_BLOCKS=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-fec support...
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Enabling gr-fec support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_FEC=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-fft support...
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Dependency FFTW3f_FOUND = TRUE
--   Enabling gr-fft support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_FFT=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-filter support...
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FFT = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Enabling gr-filter support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_FILTER=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-analog support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FFT = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FILTER = ON
--   Enabling gr-analog support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_ANALOG=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-digital support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FFT = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FILTER = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_ANALOG = ON
--   Enabling gr-digital support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_DIGITAL=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-dtv support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_ANALOG = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FILTER = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FEC = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Enabling gr-dtv support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_DTV=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-audio support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Enabling gr-audio support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_AUDIO=ON/OFF
-- Found ALSA 1.1.3
-- Checking for module 'jack'
--   No package 'jack' found
-- Checking for module 'portaudio-2.0'
--   No package 'portaudio-2.0' found
-- 
-- Configuring gr-comedi support...
--   Dependency COMEDI_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Enabling gr-comedi support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_COMEDI=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-channels support...
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FFT = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FILTER = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_ANALOG = ON
--   Enabling gr-channels support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_CHANNELS=ON/OFF
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found suitable version "3.6.8", minimum required is "2") 
-- Python checking for PyQt5 - found
-- Checking for module 'Qt5Qwt6'
--   No package 'Qt5Qwt6' found
-- QWT Version: 6.1.3
-- 
-- Configuring gr-qtgui support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency QT_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency QWT_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency ENABLE_VOLK = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FFT = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FILTER = ON
--   Dependency PYTHONLIBS_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency PYQT5_FOUND = TRUE
--   Enabling gr-qtgui support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_QTGUI=ON/OFF
-- 
-- Configuring gr-trellis support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_ANALOG = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_DIGITAL = ON
--   Enabling gr-trellis support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_TRELLIS=ON/OFF
-- Checking for module 'uhd'
--   No package 'uhd' found
-- 
-- Configuring gr-uhd support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency UHD_FOUND = 0
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FILTER = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_BLOCKS = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_ANALOG = ON
--   Disabling gr-uhd support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_UHD=ON/OFF
--   UHD Version: 
-- Python checking for Mako >= 0.4.2 - found
-- 
-- Configuring gr-utils support...
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = ON
--   Dependency ENABLE_PYTHON = ON
--   Dependency MAKO_FOUND = TRUE
--   Enabling gr-utils support.
--   Override with -DENABLE_GR_UTILS=ON/OFF
-- Python checking for click - not found
CMake Error at gr-utils/python/modtool/CMakeLists.txt:30 (message):
  Python module click is required for gr-modtool


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fit-pc/gnuradio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/fit-pc/gnuradio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Honestly, I can't understand what is causing this error!
I tried to google this error but didn't find any guidance. I even found hard to tell what is really the error!

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As said before, you **shouldn't** be builing GNU Radio from source, but just install it using `apt install gnuradio`, done.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I tried that before and got errors that i posted here and I was advised to build from the source here then I got the problem above!!! So frustrating and so confusing and such a waste of time and efforts!!! And what makes it more frustrating is the Down-Vote that I got for this posting at the time I am waiting for help and solution, what a frustrating experience!!!

Comment: If you have previous posts that explain what you're doing, always try to link to them, so that we understand why you're doing what. In any case: I'm the GNU Radio maintainer. Unless you want to *modify* GNU Radio, you should NOT be building from source.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Still, you really shouldn't have run into any problems using the binary installation; PyBOMBS hopefully is really what you need, and not another complication.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I appreciate your patience. In this case, after many failures in setting up  a real working gnuradio+uhd-usrp software, please, do me a big favor and provide me with a reliable link to some clear instructions webpage or paper on how to set up a working gnuradio+uhd-usrp. Every time I install something and I get excited and think that this is it then quickly I get shocked with another error or some problem (especially the missing blocks annoying problem)...

Comment: `apt install gnuradio` definitely installs a working GNU Radio, with UHD dependency, which allows you to use USRPs, under Mint19. I don't really have any better website, because that's just how you install software under Mint. Most people that run into problems with such installations have some half-complete source installation, a binary installation and manually copied files from *somewhere* mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/ModtoolArchitecture (install instructions)

This thread was the first one I got for the same search, so it might be something recent, installing it on the new 18.04 Ubuntu box gave me the same error and got fixed with this (as per link abocve):

```
$ pip3 install click
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).